# Sub Language C#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

I was just wondering, is it at all possible to create sort of like a "Sub-language" in C# OR C++? or would a better term be "Extension"? And can somebody please provide links/resources?

Much appreciated! :)

thanks
jason

Comment: It is not clear from the question what exactly you need. Try to elaborate.

Comment: I think you're referring to a "Domain Specific Language." Googling for that yields fruitful results like http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/YourFirstDSL.aspx

Comment: Throwing a word like "Sub-language" into open space without telling what you mean will probably trigger lots of fanciful answers. It would be more effective to explain just a little what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think a better term would be whatever the *opposite* of "Extension" is. "Closing" would be nicely ironic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think maybe the phrase you are looking for is [Domain Specific Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language)?

One example is Boo for .net

Book on Boo: http://www.manning.com/rahien/

[Link on building DSLs for .Net](http://www.infoq.com/articles/dsl-on-the-clr)

Answer (score 2):

The way I've always looked at C++ programming is that I am extending the language by creating new types to solve new problems.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you consider a "sub-language".

You could create just about anything you want if you're willing to put the time and effort into learning how to utilize the [DLR (Dynamic Language Runtime)](http://dlr.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific?  You can build your own dynamic languages on the [DLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Language_Runtime).  Also [here](http://dlr.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

For simplicities sake I'm making my contribution 'your-very-own-scriptlanguage'.
If you are not concerned about pre-compiled code but instead want something compiled in runtime, you could look into making your own script language and write a parser for it so you can execute it in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Well, .net is a multi-language platform. You would need to write a compiler of course, and you can write that compiler in any language, including C#. I've started a series about [writing a brainf**k compiler in C#](http://www.stum.de/2010/04/09/writing-a-bf-compiler-for-net-part-1-explanation-of-the-language-and-interpreter-in-c/).

A compiler doesn't have to be Languague-to-IL, you can also write a compiler that compiles Language-To-C# and then uses the C# compiler (Some people call those compilers pre-processors). You just need to be sure that whatever you do can be translated to C# (or C++ if that's what you want to do). Then you can just define your keywords and language tokens.

Just keep in mind that creating new, insular programming languages can be a maintenance debt in the future and often is a sign of too much "[Not invented here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here)"-syndrome.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/) to implement a DSL and it worked out great.  Keep in mind it's still very much a WIP and you'll probably find it pretty nice to work with.